# Is it possible to find Normalized Root Mean Square Error (NRMSE) of Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) in R?

Tags: r, regression, rms

I have code in R that calculates the RMSE from a Linear Regression model:

```
library(caTools)
library(hydroGOF)

Time <- c(406, 472, 4462, 172770, 172430, 176570) 
V1 <- c(-2.312226542, -3.043540624, -2.303349568, 2.007418028, -0.446950896, -0.515512845) 
Amount <- c(0, 529, 239.93, 3.99, 60.5, 9.81) 
ClassABC <- c(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)

df <- data.frame(Time, V1, Amount, ClassABC)

df

set.seed(2)
split <- sample.split(df, SplitRatio=0.7)

train <- subset(df, split=TRUE)
Actual <- subset(df, split=FALSE)

# Create the model
Model <- lm(ClassABC ~.,data=train)

#Prediction
Prediction <- predict(Model, Actual)

#Comparing predicted vs actual model
plot(Actual$ClassABC,type = "l",lty= 1.8,col = "red")
lines(Prediction, type = "l", col = "blue")
plot(Prediction,type = "l",lty= 1.8,col = "blue")

#Finding Accuracy
rmse <- sqrt(mean(Prediction-df2$ClassABC)^2)/diff(range(df2$ClassABC))==1
rmse
```

The output for the RMSE is 3.805235e-15, is it possible to normalize this using NRMSE in R? If so, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "NRMSE"? How do you want to normalize your RMSE? Incidentally, a RMSE that is essentially zero strongly suggests to me that something is not quite right.

Comment: NRMSE is the normalized root mean square function in R. I want to use it to transform the current RMSE value into a percentage (without hard code). I too have noticed the low RMSE value, my datum ranges from 0-1000 so an RMSE of 3.8 means the model is highly inaccurate. @StephanKolassa

Comment: However, the appearence of the test and predicted models itself implys that the model is accurate, so it's contradicting @StephanKolassa

Comment: There is no function `NRMSE()` in base R, nor `nrmse()`, so I assume you are using a package. Please tell us which one. If you want to transform your RMSE into a percentage, you will need to specify a meaningful baseline (a percentage of *what*?). And your RMSE is not $3.8$, it is $3.8e-15=3.8\times 10^{-15} =0.0000000000000038$, which still looks essentially like zero.

Comment: The package I am using is hydroGOF, I am trying to find the percentage of the matching data points found in `Class`, with the total number of datums (1000). I can probably do this in R code when hard coding but I want it to be dynamic if a user uploads different data, hence the use of the function. @StephanKolassa

Comment: With it being essentially 0, this means that my expression for rmse is incorrect aswel. The function CaTools is also being used

Comment: @Nick I normalize RMSE all the time. The formula is 1-(RMSE(x)/Mean(x)). In R you can do this by `library(ModelMetrics); 1-(rmse(Actual$ClassABC,                                   predict.train(Model, Actual)))/ mean(Actual$ClassABC,)))*100`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the help page `?nrmse`, it normalizes the RMSE either by the standard deviation of the actuals, or by their range, depending on whether `norm="sd"` or `norm="maxmin"`. So either

```
sqrt(mean(Prediction-thedata2$Class)^2)/sd(thedata2$Class)
```

or

```
sqrt(mean(Prediction-thedata2$Class)^2)/diff(range(thedata2$Class))
```

should do what you want.

(Since your target variable is called `Class`, I wonder whether this is a categorical variable, in which case all of the RMSE, the SD and the range would not be defined.)

Comment: Changed the column in the file to 'ClassABC', and matched with the variables in the code.

 After running both functions the result is still:

`> sqrt(mean(Prediction-thedata2$ClassABC)^2)/diff(range(thedata2$ClassABC))


[1] 3.805235e-15`

Comment: If `diff(range(thedata2$ClassABC))==1`, then that is to be expected. I suggest you edit your question to include a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/452096), otherwise we can't help you very well.

Comment: The output was FALSE, I have edited the question so it is a minimum working example.

Comment: Your question is *not* a *working* example. We do not have access to data on your hard drive. Please simulate data within the code so your code runs on our machines.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient with me, I have added a dataframe so it should be good to go @Stephan

Comment: Does the code fit well? @StephanKolassa

Comment: I'll take a look later today or tomorrow.

Comment: I am getting closer to the solution, the RMSE is very low because the `ClassABC` data is either 1 or 0, the linear regression prediction model is not predicting 1 or 0, but 0.7, 1.5, 1.3, 1.2... etc For it to be accurate the prediction model must only predict 1 or 0 for the `ClassABC` column.

Comment: Take a look at `split`. It has length 4, not 6 (the number of rows of `df`) as it should be. This is because you should not feed an entire `data.frame` to `split.sample()`, only a vector. See `?split.sample`. As a consequence, *both* `train` and `Actual` contain all of `df`. So your evaluation happens on the exact same set you trained your model on. It's good practice to always visually inspect your objects (here `split`, `train` and `Actual`) to see whether they are at least *structured* as expected.

Comment: Also, in your data, `Time` almost perfectly predicts `ClassABC`, especially together with `V1`. This (together with the in-sample evaluation) is why you are getting a very small error. Also, as I suspected, `diff(range(df$ClassABC))==1`, so if you scale the RMSE by the range to get the NRMSE, you divide by 1 and get the exact same number as the original RMSE.

Comment: Thanks that's cleared things up a bit, except how would I change the length of `split` from 4 to 6? Would I need to create more columns? If so, that's is going to be impossible as my real data set has 1000+ rows. @StephanKolassa

Comment: `sample.split()` expects a vector, not a data.frame as its argument, so use `sample.split(df$ClassABC,0.7)`. Also, change the `subset()` commands and do not use `split=TRUE` and `split=FALSE`. Instead, use `subset(df,split)` and `subset(df,!split)`. Check the objects you create and see whether they make sense before proceeding. Good luck!